# nextval y currval oracle

Tags: oracle

Intento sacar el valor de la secuencia en el momento, tengo un NEXTVAL, y necesito poner un CURRVAL pero el problema es que no se donde ponerlo y como ponelo, alguien que me pueda ayudar.

```
   using (var conexion = new OracleConnection(conexionString))
            {
                int id = 0;
                try
                {
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO EJIGSADM.CSV_KQ_TESTING (ID,XXXXXX, XXXXX, XXXX_XXXX, XXXXX, XXXXXXX,XXXXX,XXXXXX) VALUES (:ID, :X , :XXXXX , :XXXXX_XXXX , :XXXXX , :XXXXXXXX, :XXXXX, :XXXXXX)";
                    conexion.Open();
                    var transaction = conexion.BeginTransaction();
                    using (var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT  XXXXXXXX.XXXX_XX_XXXXXXX_XX.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL", conexion))
                    {
                        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(tabla);
                        Int32.TryParse(tabla.Rows[0][0].ToString(), out id);
                    }

                    if (id > 0)
                    {

                        using (var comando = new OracleCommand(sql, conexion))
                        {
                            comando.Parameters.Clear();
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":ID", id);
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", XXXXXX);
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", XXXXXX);
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", XXXXXX);
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", XXXXXX);
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", XXXXXX);
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", XXXXXX);
                            comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", XXXXXX);
                            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    string insert = "INSERT INTO XXXXXXX.XXX_XX_XXXXXX_XXX (ID_XXXX,XXXXX_XXXX,XXXXXXXX,XXXXX,XXXXXX,XXXXXX,XXXX) VALUES (:ID_XXXXX ,:XXXX_XXXXX ,:XXXXXXXX ,:XXXXX ,:XXXXX ,:XXXXXX ,:XXXX)";
                    using (var comando = new OracleCommand(insert, conexion))
                    {
                        foreach (Body b in DATA)
                        {
                                if (b.XXXXX_XXXX != null)
                                {
                                    comando.Parameters.Clear();
                                    comando.Parameters.Add(":ID_XXXXX", id);
                                    comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXX_XXXX", b.XXXXX_XXXX);
                                    comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXXXX", b.XXXXXXXX);
                                    comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXX", b.XXXX);
                                    comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", b.XXXXXX);
                                    comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXXXX", b.XXXXX_XXXX);

                                    if (b.XXXXX_XXXX != "XXXXX" && b.XXXXX_XXXX != "" && b.XXXXX_XXXX != "XXXX")
                                    {
                                        sql = "UPDATE  XXXXXXX.XXX_XX_XXXXXX_XXX SET XXXXXX = 'NO' ,  FPY ='NO PASO' WHERE ID = :ID";
                                        using (var comand = new OracleCommand(sql, conexion))
                                        {
                                            comand.Parameters.Clear();
                                            comand.Parameters.Add(":ID", Convert.ToInt32(id));
                                            comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        }

                                    }
                                    comando.Parameters.Add(":XXXX", b.XXXXX_XXXX);
                                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }                            
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Es posible que no hayan datos en la tabla que coincidan.

Comment: Hola, agrega mas información para entender el problema por favor, como la estructura y ejemplos del contenido de la tabla.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres saber? ¿El último valor de la secuencia? Lo que estás haciendo no es lo más adecuado.

Comment: actualización de post

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo esto te debe servir:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO EJIGSADM.CSV_KQ_TESTING (ID, ... ) VALUES (XXXXXXXX.XXXX_XX_XXXXXXX_XX.NEXTVAL, ...)";
```

Para los insert coloca *secuencia.nextval* en el lugar del parámetro.

Para update usa currval.

Para hacer todo esto debes estar en la misma transacción, claro.